# Error parsing array through IF Statement

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I need to loop through an entire 2D array (OldTable) to check that Column1 has a value of 1 and Col7 is not empty (null). If the above conditions are true then push the current (i) arrays of elements into newTable. 
My snippet of JS is as follow...

```
var newTable = [];  
  for (var i=1; i<OldTable.length; i++){     
    if(OldTable[i][0]==1 && OldTable[i][7]!==null){
      newTable.push(OldTable[i]);      
    }    
  }
```

Seems like a fairly straight forward thing to do but currently hitting brick wall with this error...

> TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. (line 80, file
>   "Code"

I have tried to reduce the if statement to just...

```
if(OldTable[i][0]==1){
```

...but still the same error.
I'm able to display the array element just fine using...

```
Browser.msgBox(OldTable[50][0]);
```

I'm fairly new to JS so could be a simple silly error someone could point out.

UPDATE: In trying to simplying naming, I've actually made it more difficult with conflicting terminology, so have going through and updated the variable names used.

Comment: did you mean `newArray` instead of `Array` inside of your loop?

Comment: What is `Array`? Check if its of proper type

Comment: `Array` ??? like, the built-in Array object that comes with every javascript engine since the 90's?

Comment: If you've called your own array `Array`, change the name, it conflicts with the JavaScript type `Array`. Try to use meaningful names for your variables, it makes your code easier to understand.

Comment: @JaromandaX though its a bad name for a variable, its valid. :-p

Comment: essentially, I'm hoping keep the elements in the array that pass the filter test and delete all other row that fails. Unfortunately can't work out how to do that, which I then had to resort to writing filtered elements into a new and empty array using push.

Comment: how is the var 'Array' built, which data in it ? Are you sure that its indexes are (consecutive) numbers and not strings ?
PS please not that you stast looping from 1 and not from 0

Comment: As commented before `Array` is a valid name (*though bad as per convention*).You can check **[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/apmrkdgc/)** (*Please run it few times as logic is based on randoms*). Issue lies in its value. Please check if `Array` is Array of Arrays. Edit: [OP's code](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/apmrkdgc/1/). @user1488934 Please not that `Arrays` are passed by reference and any manipulation on `newArray` will reflect in `Array` as well.

Comment: Are you sure your OldTable is defined and has any data? The error means that you are trying to read from an object which is not yet defined. Try moving your script to the bottom of the page.

Comment: @ankith `OldTable` is defined and has length property as code is entering loop. Issue is in value of `OldTable[i]`. Its not an array

Comment: @Rajesh my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work if, as noted in the comment by @Massimo, you change your loop from starting at `i=1` to `i=0`, as shown below. Also, just to whet your appetite for more modern tools within JavaScript, I also include an essentially identical solution to the problem using ES6/ES2015.

```js
var myArray = [
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'foo'    ], // should pass
  [9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'foo'    ], // should fail
  [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 'foo'    ], // should pass
  [1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, null     ], // should fail
  [0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, null     ], // should fail
  [1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, undefined], // should pass
  [1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 'foo'    ]  // should pass
];

function f1(array) {
  var newArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i][0] == 1 && array[i][7] !== null) {
      newArray.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}

const f2 = array => array.filter(e => e[0] === 1 && e[7] !== null);

console.log(f1(myArray));
console.log(f2(myArray));
```

Comment: Yes changing loop to start from `0` and using `.filter` are good suggestions but how do they solve the problem?

Comment: you are a legend! changing i starting value did work for me, another newbee error. I'll definitely have a play with your sample code to see where they can applied. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Rajesh, your comment is totally valid, as my answer didn't really seem to address the error the OP was getting. However, now that OP suggests that "my" answer actually solves the problem, I must emphasize again (as I did in my original answer) that what seems to have been the original problem was originally solved by Massimo _(can't link to Rajesh and Massimo in same comment)_, not me. Anyway, glad I could help in a round-about way, and hopefully the ES2015 version will inspire.

Comment: @AndrewWillems Glad you wish to share credits with others. Keep up the good work. I'm still not sure how can changing `i` to `0` will solve the error, but it did. Good for OP but not sure if this adds anything to portal. Just would like to advice you to wait next time for more clarity. Answering with partial knowledge can attract downvotes. :-)

Comment: @user1488934 An advice to you is to use better naming convention. Try to avoid generic terms. Name should signify purpose. If not used properly, you will have to read through code just to make sense of *what and why*.